# Angularjs radio buttons become multiple selected

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am learning angular and use radio button in my program. I found a problem that I can't explain it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app = "myApp">
 <div class="container" ng-controller="myController">
  <div><p style="margin: 30px auto"></p></div>
  <label class="radio-inline" ng-repeat = "name in names" for = "{{name}}">
   <input type="radio" ng-model="my.favorite" ng-value="name" id="{{name}}" name="favorite"></input>
   {{name}}
  </label>

  <p>Your favorite is {{my.favorite}}</p>

  <div>
      <select ng-model="choosenone" ng-options="method.value as method.label for method in contactMethods">
       <option value="">Tel or Email</option>
      </select>
   <p>You choose {{choosenone}}</p>
     </div>
 </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
     angular.module('myApp',[])
     .controller("myController",['$scope','$log',function ($scope,$log) {
      //radio choices
      $scope.names = ['pizza', 'unicorns', 'robots'];
         $scope.my = { favorite: 'unicorns' };

         //select chocices
         $scope.contactMethods = [{value:"tel",label:"Tel."},{value:"email",label:"Email"}];
         $scope.choosenone;
     }]);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This code works fine, but if I make $scope.my in the javascript code equal to an empty string or undefined, and make the ng-model on the radio input HTML tag equal to "my", then the radio buttons can be mutiple selected. What's the reason?

Comment: check this jsfiddle, your code seems to work fine http://jsfiddle.net/p3jg6x24/

Answer (score 0):

```
<label class="radio-inline" ng-repeat="name in names" for="{{name}}">
  <input type="radio" ng-model="my.favorite" ng-value="name" id="{{name}}" name="favorite" />
  {{name}}
</label>
```

Probably because they all have the same id - change that. So for example *id="{{name}}-$index"* and it will work the way you want. If you keep the same name, only one of them can be selected.